# How to display folder files name (inc korean name) in php?

Tags: php

is there any chance you could show files name inside folder? Also will it support korean, chinese and other language names?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is currently an [open bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30195) with this issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the a character encoding for output that supports the characters your file names have. I’d recommend you to use [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as it can encode any [Unicode character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set).

So try this:

```
// set the MIME type and character encoding
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');

$files = glob('*');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $file, '<br>';
}
```